# RGB Value of Entity of DWG File

Tags: colors, dwg, eyeshot

1. I have a DWG CAD file in which a lot of lines are drawn.
2. The lines have different color each.
3. I Loaded this DWG CAD file to ViewPortLayout in Devdept.Eyshot

Q. Can I get color information such as RGB Values of CAD File entities to use in c# code??
   Is there any class that I can get it ?

Please give me any idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Each entity has *ColorMethod* and *Color* properties.
If *ColorMethod=ByEntity* then you can check *entity.Color* property.
If *ColorMethod=ByLayer* then you can use the *entity.LayerName* to get the related Layer and check the *layer.Color* property.